# ASP.NET MVC Binding to a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, model-binding

I'm trying to bind dictionary values within MVC.

Within the action I have:

```
model.Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();

model.Params.Add("Value1", "1");
model.Params.Add("Value2", "2");
model.Params.Add("Value3", "3");
```

and within the view I have:

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Model.Params)
{ 
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="Params.Key" value="@kvp.Key" />
    @Html.TextBox("Params[" + kvp.Key + "]")
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

But the view doesn't display the initial values, and when the form is submitted the `Params` property is null?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

you should take a look to this post from scott hanselman:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

The default binder just understand dictionaries in the format:

```
params[0].key = kvp.key
params[0].value = kvp.value
```

The index of the param must be sequential, starting from 0 and without any gaps. The current helpers don't support this, so you should create the form input fields by yourself.

you can of course implement your own binder, like this one:
http://siphon9.net/loune/2009/12/a-intuitive-dictionary-model-binder-for-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Surprisingly, one of the very few (or even the only one) answer that is correct. Other 
answers try to pass the dictionary's key as the params index argument (params[key]) which just doesn't work. The only way to index it is using a sequence starting from 0 and only then use .key/.value.

Answer (score 99):

In ASP.NET MVC 4, the default model binder will bind dictionaries using the typical dictionary indexer syntax `property[key]`.

If you have a **`Dictionary<string, string>`** in your model, you can now bind back to it directly with the following markup:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyDictionary[MyKey]" value="MyValue" />
```

For example, if you want to use a set of checkboxes to select a subset of a dictionary's elements and bind back to the same property, you can do the following:

```
@foreach(var kvp in Model.MyDictionary)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="@("MyDictionary[" + kvp.Key + "]")"
        value="@kvp.Value" />
}
```

Comment: Can somebody provide any links to a more detailed answer? Tried for Dictionary<int, bool> and it didn't work out, so I had to go with the old indexer syntax.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work with numeric keys, but does with strings.

Comment: @Ant P I have two input textboxes one for key and one for value . how do i map these ?

Comment: How can i use this / bind the dictionary when adding the fields dynamically to html Dom with JavaScript? Ok

Comment: Note: this only works with `Dictionary<string, string>` and not with other types (such as `Dictionary<string, object>`).

Answer (score 28):

Building on @AntP's answer, there is an even less verbose way, letting MVC do more of the work (at least with `TextBoxFor()` on a `Dictionary<string, string>` - I haven't tried `CheckBoxFor()` on a `Dictionary<xxx, bool>`):

```
@foreach(var kvp in Model.MyDictionary)
{
    @Html.Label(kvp.Key);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDictionary[kvp.Key]);
}
```

Comment: `CheckBoxFor` would work with a `Dict<string, bool>` but it wouldn't work in any scenario where you want to bind back specific key/value pairs where the value is not just a bool - to do that you need to build the markup yourself (as in my example).

Comment: Why should this only work for booleans? I got this to work for Dict<string, string> as well, and I don't see why it shouldn't work for other data types as well.

Comment: @KaiWeber - This probably works for any `Dictionary<X, Y>` (in fact, `<string, string>` is what I use in my answer). However, I haven't tested it with anything else. What I think Ant P says is that it only works for typed dictionaries (`Dictionary<>`), and not non-generic collections like [IDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx)

Comment: I just tried this using a `Dictionary<Enum, string>`, which didn't work. If I use a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead, it works. Anybody has an explanation for this?

Comment: My experience was that the value can be anything, but the key had to be a `string` instead of an `int`. Maybe the model binder confuses it with a positional argument.