# how to access Javascript multidimensional array in MVC controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, multidimensional-array

I have to pass array of filters like this:

Script Code:

```
return { CustomFilter: options.filter.filters };
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

From Firebug:

```
CustomFilter[0][field]      ItemName
CustomFilter[0][operator]   startswith
CustomFilter[0][value]      testing Value

CustomFilter[1][field]      BrandName
CustomFilter[1][operator]   startswith
CustomFilter[1][value]      testing Value 1
```

Posted values are:[image]

But i am unable to received these on Controller side.

i tried like this:

```
public ActionResult ReadOperation( string[][] CustomFilter)
```

Also like this:

```
public ActionResult ReadOperation( Filter[] CustomFilter)
public class Filter
{
     public string field { get; set; }
     public string @operator { get; set; }
     public string value { get; set; }
}
```

But didn't work. Please Suggest.

[image: Tried with model approach]

Thank you.

---

**Solution Found with Json deserialization**

Script code changed to:

```
 return { CustomFilter: JSON.stringify(CustomFilter) };
```

Controller Code changed to:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public ActionResult ReadOperation(MyViewModel model)
{
    var filters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(model.CustomFilter, typeof(CustomFilter[]));
}

public class MyViewModel 
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
    public int sort { get; set; }
}


public class CustomFilter
{
     public string field { get; set; }
     public string @operator { get; set; }
     public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Result View in controller:

[image]

Comment: Does your code compile at all?

Comment: Yes,it is also showing count 2 as i am passing 2 filters, but values of field,operator and value is showing null.

Comment: Can you post the raw JSON? Firebug should show what is posted.

Comment: I have added Firebug image of posted values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 4, and cannot change the parameter names, maybe you can define a custom model in this way:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string,string>[] CustomerFilter { get; set; }
    public string filter { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
    public int sort { get; set; }
}
```

Then, at the controller:

```
public ActionResult ReadOperation(MyViewModel model){ ... }
```

It seems that the notation used in the parameters generated by your grid is for [dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683004/806975). Haven't tried a collection of Dictionaries, though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Although i had already done this with json De serialization. But i tried your way also and it worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an error with model structure.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Filter[] CustomFilter { get; set; }
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }
}
```

Try to use this type for model binding.

```
public ActionResult ReadOperation(MyViewModel model)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ufuk .i have tried as you told but still it is showing CustomFilter as null.

Comment: Yes @Ufuk i noticed that, I had already tried with correct property name "CustomFilter". Again properties values were null. i had attached a screen shot from controller at bottom of Question, you can check that.

Comment: @Gerry Can you show your form HTML. It looks like model binding won't work with current format.

Comment: i have done this with Newtonsoft.json Object deserialization. returned this from { CustomFilter: JSON.stringify(CustomFilter) }; and deserialized in controller. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(model.CustomFilter, typeof(Filter[])); Thanks @Ufuk for your model approach:)

Answer (score 1):

In the post, try to send the data as this:

```
CustomFilter[0].Field      ItemName
CustomFilter[0].Operator   startswith
CustomFilter[0].Value      testing Value

CustomFilter[1].Field      BrandName
CustomFilter[1].Operator   startswith
CustomFilter[1].Value      testing Value 1
```

And at the controller:

```
public ActionResult ReadOperation(Filter[] CustomFilter)
```

Having a `Filter` class defined as:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string Field { set; get; }
    public string Operator { set; get; }
    public string Value { set; get; }
}
```

(Be careful with the capital letters).

Or if you want to use the model approach, as Ufuk suggests, and having the same `Filter` class:

- Model:

  ```
  public class MyViewModel
  {
      public Filter[] CustomerFilter { get; set; }
      public string Filter { get; set; }
      public string Group { get; set; }
      public int Page { get; set; }
      public int PageSize { get; set; }
      public int Sort { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Parameters in POST:

  ```
  CustomFilter[0].Field      ItemName
  CustomFilter[0].Operator   startswith
  CustomFilter[0].Value      testing Value

  CustomFilter[1].Field      BrandName
  CustomFilter[1].Operator   startswith
  CustomFilter[1].Value      testing Value 1

  Filter                     ItemName~startswith~'12'~and~BrandName~startswith~'123'
  Group
  Page                       1
  PageSize                   15
  Sort
  ```
- Controller

  ```
  public ActionResult ReadOperation(MyViewModel model)
  ```

See this link: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Thanks @Guillermo, But i can pass values to controller as you told because these are sent by kendo Grid itself. Other wise i have to modify filter request using script(dont want to do that).

Comment: I see, so that is the default format of Kendo Grid parameters. The only way then would be to make a custom model binder.