# Unable to read submitted form data from MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have the following form that contains data in a multi-dimensional array that I want to send to my server. The problem is I can't see to pick this data up in my controller.

**index.html**

```
<form id="my-form" action="/Home/TestingMethod" method="post">
    <table id="people" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Owns Item</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Danny</td>
                <td class="items">
                    <select name="PersonList[1]Item[]" class="form-control">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Keys">Keys</option>
                        <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**MyModel**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<int> PersonList { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult TestingMethod(MyModel model)
{
    List<int> list_of_people = model.PersonList;
    return Json("I am the server, I got your data.");
}
```

The issue is that `list_of_people` contains 0 elements.

**Form data submitted**

```
PersonList[1]Item[]:Phone
```

related: [how to access Javascript multidimensional array in MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996191/how-to-access-javascript-multidimensional-array-in-mvc-controller)

Comment: your `PersonList` is a List of int, but the value of your select is a string?

Comment: the `Person` in my form supplies an int 1. `Person[1]`

Comment: What's with all the down votes?

Comment: so what are you expecting? a list of ints in `MyModel.PersonList`?

Comment: Yes I want to get a list of ints based on my Person[1] data, ignoring the Item[] value for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming convention of your select field is incorrect. In order to match your model structure it should look like this:

```
<select name="PersonList[0]" class="form-control">
<select name="PersonList[1]" class="form-control">
<select name="PersonList[2]" class="form-control">
...
```

Because the `PersonList` property is just an array of integers. Also make sure that you are sending integer values if you want to be able to bind to integers:

```
<option value="0">Keys</option>
<option value="1">Phone</option>
...
```

And if you want to allow for empty values make sure that your list is defined as a nullable integers:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<int?> PersonList { get; set; }
}
```

and now you could do this:

```
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">Keys</option>
<option value="1">Phone</option>
...
```

If on the other hand it was a complex property:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
}
```

where Person is defined like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then you could do this:

```
<select name="PersonList[0].Items[0].SomeProperty" class="form-control">
<select name="PersonList[0].Items[1].SomeProperty" class="form-control">
<select name="PersonList[1].Items[0].SomeProperty" class="form-control">
...
```

I would also recommend you going through the [`following post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) which explains how the model binder works and what is the naming convention that it expects.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm after, it's a custom form I have which doesn't directly/easily map using the standard binder to my model. I will give this a go and see if I can get it working.

Comment: I have amended to PersonList but my controller is still not picking it up. model.PersonList.Count = 0

Comment: Since PersonList is an array of integers, make sure that your options are also integers: `<option value="0">Keys</option><option value="1">Phone</option>`. Another important aspect is that the indexes should start at 0, not 1 as shown in my code: `<select name="PersonList[0]" class="form-control">`

Comment: Well my integers don't start at 0 because that relates to an ID in my database. Does it have to start at 0 in order for it to work?

Comment: I am talking about the indexes, not the values. You could very well have the following: `<select name="PersonList[0]" class="form-control"><option value="12345">Keys</option></select>`. Now the first element of the PersonList collection (at index 0) will have the value of `12345` which could reflect the ID in your database. But the index should **always** start at 0, that's how lists and arrays work in .NET.