# Passing a dictionary to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel that I'm trying to pass to my controller which contains a dictionary. I'm able to get everything to show up correctly in the view, however when I got to post to my controller I never get the the StudentKeys dictionary to go through, however all other information goes through fine.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BulkEditStudentRecordsAdultEd", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "EditStudentAdultEd", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AdultEdAgencyCd)
        foreach (var item in Model.StudentKeys)
        {
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Key)
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Value)
        }
        <h1>@Model.StudentKeys.Count</h1>
        <div class="row inputRow">
            @Html.BootstrapDropDownListFor(m => m.DistrictCd, Model.DistrictCodes, "col-md-5", labelText: "District:", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "DistrictCd" })
            @Html.BootstrapDropDownListFor(m => m.SchoolCd, Model.SchoolCodes, "col-md-5", labelText: "School:", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "SchoolCd" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
            <button id="SaveStudentBulkEdit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save <span class="badge">0</span></button>
            <button id="CancelStudentBulkEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>  
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomAuthorize(DiplomaRoles.SchoolStaff, DiplomaRoles.StateAdultEdManagement, DiplomaRoles.SchoolAdmin, DiplomaRoles.StateAdmin)]
public ActionResult BulkEditStudentRecordsAdultEd(EditStudentAdultEdViewModel vm) //All other information from my view model gets through
{
    var keys = vm.StudentKeys; //Empty
    var DistrictCd = vm.DistrictCd; //Ok
    var SchoolCd = vm.SchoolCd; //Ok
}
```

View Model

```
 public class EditStudentAdultEdViewModel
 {
     public EditStudentAdultEdViewModel()
     {
         StudentKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     }
     public string DistrictCd {get; set;}
     public string SchoolCd {get; set;}
     public string IdentificationNbr{ get; set; } 
     public int DuplicateNbr { get; set; }
     public Dictionary<string, string> StudentKeys { get; set; }
     public string AdultEdAgencyCd { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: There is a relatively old duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary, but I am not exactly sure that this should be closed as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC already puts everything that was submitted into a dictionary for you.

```
public ActionResult BulkEditStudentRecordsAdultEd(FormCollection vm)
{
    // to access an item, do this:  vm["inputName"]
}
```

If you want the default modelbinder to bind for you into a different dictionary, you can do so by having inputs with correct names:

```
<input type="hidden" name="vm[KeyString]" value="ValueString" />
```