# MVC - Assigning Values to Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add `dictionary` values in the `View`, Following is my Code :-

```
public class TO
{
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public int EmployeeName { get; set; }

     public Dictionary<string, double> Dic1 { get; set; }
     public Dictionary<string, double> Dic2 { get; set; }
}
```

View :-

```
@model List<Models.TO>


@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
{
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EmployeeId)
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EmployeeName)

          ....
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Dic1, Value = "") // Psuedo

}
```

As i have assigned values to `EmployeeId` & `EmployeeName` which i get in `POST` method in the `Controller`, How to assign values to `Dictionary`?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put the whole dictionary into a hidden field. Dictionary are enumerable, so you have to work out for each key/value.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
{
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EmployeeId)
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EmployeeName)

      ....
      foreach (string key in Dic1.Keys)
      { 
              @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Dic1[key])
      }

}
```