# asp.mvc using DayOfWeek enum as key in dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

My aim is to loop through all the days in my dictionary so I don't have to explicity list every day. As well as if I do that, there will be a lot of duplicate.

I've made a model containing a dictionary as a property like this:

```
public class ReWeekRowModel() 
{
public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, ReDayModel> Days { get; set; }
}
```

The ReDayModel class above, only contains the properties Hours and Comments.
Here is the constructor for the model:

```
    public ReWeekRowModel()
    {
        Id = ReChronoModels.RandNum.Next(100);
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        Days = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, ReDayModel>
        {
            {DayOfWeek.Monday, new ReDayModel()},
            {DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new ReDayModel()},
            {DayOfWeek.Wednesday, new ReDayModel()},
            {DayOfWeek.Thursday, new ReDayModel()},
            {DayOfWeek.Friday, new ReDayModel()},
            {DayOfWeek.Saturday, new ReDayModel()},
            {DayOfWeek.Sunday, new ReDayModel()}
        };
    }
```

I'm prepopulating a couple of ReWeekRowModel at launch, and from the index page, i click the edit link (this is based on the shipped solution in visual studio).
I manage to get the data showing correctly in the edit page.

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<DayOfWeek, ReDayModel> day in Model.Days)
    {
       @Html.Label(day.ToString(), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Days[day.Key].Hours, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Days[day.Key].Hours, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
        @Html.Label("Comments:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Days[day.Key].Comments, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Days[day.Key].Comments, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    }
```

Works fine, and shows me the Hours and Comments of the containing day.

But when I try to do the PostBack it tries to update with the key as a string, not as a DayOfWeek.

When debugging in Chrome:

- Days[Monday].Hours:5.5
- Days[Monday].Comments:Working hard
- Days[Tuesday].Hours:5.5
- Days[Tuesday].Comments:Done with work n stuff
- Days[Wednesday].Hours:2
- Days[Wednesday].Comments:
- Days[Thursday].Hours:0
- Days[Thursday].Comments:
- Days[Friday].Hours:0
- Days[Friday].Comments:
- Days[Saturday].Hours:0
- Days[Saturday].Comments:
- Days[Sunday].Hours:0
- Days[Sunday].Comments:

This results in a crash at the index page:

```
Line 99:                 <td class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
Line 100:                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.Days[DayOfWeek.Monday].Hours)
Line 101:                </td>
```

I know I can circumvent this by just using the string version as key instead, but I want to use the the DayOfWeek enum!

Is it possible in an easy way, or should I just use string as the key?

Comment: Why not just simplify this and add a `DayOfWeek` property to the model so you just use `List<ReDayModel>`?

Comment: What if you have a List of `Hours` in your `DayOfWeek` class? Same goes for the `Comments`. This way you would just have to create a `DayOfWeek` and then add an hour or a comment whenever you like using your Day

Comment: But if you do want to write a lot of extra code, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary) for how to bind to a Dictionary

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes for the foreach, a List would be smarter I guess. But elsewhere in the code, I'd prefer using the DayOfWeek enum instead of remembering the index for the given day.

Comment: In your other code, you can still use the `DayOfWeek` enum through a LINQ statement, and don't have to remember the index.

Comment: A `foreach` on `List<T>` will not work - it needs to be a `for` loop (or a custom `EditorTemplate` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943))