# ASP.NET MVC 5 Binding to dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, post

I have a string dictionary in my model and I would like its key value pairs to show up in the view and then in my POST values. Tried to do it by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary) and the [suggested blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) without luck.

The items of the dictionary are shown in the view but there's always null in the post data. Shall I add some attributes to the model class properties?

Some details of my solution:

Model:

```
public class WorkPlaceModel {
    public Dictionary<string, string> WorkplaceData = null;
}
```

View third version, none of them worked:

```
foreach (var kvp in Model.WorkplaceData)
{
    @Html.Label(kvp.Key);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkplaceData[kvp.Key]);
}
```

Comment: `WorkplaceData` is a field, not a property and the `DefaultModelBinder` does not bind fields. Add `{ get; set; }`

Comment: Stupid me, thanks.