# C# MVC - Parse a json dictionary posted to controller

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a *Javascript* library that passes a dictionary in the post data like this:

```
sort[columnName] = asc
```

If I do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult tableData(Dictionary<string,string> sort)
```

It doesn't parse it. Do I need to parse this by hand? Or is there a way?

I'm Sure this question has been asked before but due to the syntax it seems impossible to find.

Comment: Have you tried parameter as `Dictionary<string, object> sort`?

Comment: You can always try with dynamic object and see if the problem is really in mapping/parsing.

Comment: The issue is that it needs to be a dictionary:

sort[UserName]=asc&sort[Phone]=desc

If there are multiple keys, I need them.

Comment: Nevermind, found it. I am passing the parameters correctly and I do have the right format for the dictionary so there must be something completely different that is out somewhere. So this question is moot.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18683004/881954

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found it. I am passing the parameters correctly and I do have the right format for the dictionary so there must be something completely different that is out somewhere. So this question is moot. stackoverflow.com/a/18683004/881954