# Quicker/Easier/Efficient way to set/bind HtmlHelper.CheckBoxFor for big model

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a class that has many properties that I want to bind to the View. Typing one by the time is quite painful and hard to maintain, so was wondering if there was an easier way of doing so.

Current Model:

```
public class test
{
    public bool a { get; set; } 
    public bool b { get; set; } 
    public bool c { get; set; } 
    .
    .
    .
    public bool x { get; set; } 
    public bool y { get; set; } 
    public bool z { get; set; } 

}
```

Current Controller:

```
public ActionResult checkbox()
{
    var viewModel = new test();
    return View(viewModel);

}
```

Current View:

```
@model Test.Program.test

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.a)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.a)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.b)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.b)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.c)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.c)
.
.
.
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.x)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.x)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.y)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.y)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.z)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.z)
```

The View part is the part that is horrifying to me.

Edit: 
Variable names are just for example.

Edit2:
Eventually, I came up with some stupid hacky way based on Soufiane Tahiri answer.

```
@foreach (var prop in test.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //here by adding the model in front will cause the model to bind with the response
        @Html.CheckBox("test." + prop.Name)
        @Html.Label(prop.Name)
    }
```

Comment: Have a dictionary of name and bool value in model. Loop over it to create checkboxes.

Comment: @Reniuz But by doing so won't the checkbox not be binded with the model?

Comment: Have you tried using `@Html.EditorForModel()`?

Comment: I am not sure, but [others tried it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflexion and loop through your model properties:

```
    @foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
     @Html.CheckBox(prop.Name)
     @Html.Label(prop.Name)
    }
```

A working snippet: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4hiOZr

Comment: This was my exact instinct, but unfortunately by doing so, the View will not be binded with the Model.

Comment: If it's not binding the problem would be probably something else