# How to post List of Dictionary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a client ( in this case POSTMAN) that is posting collection of object. The properties of the object are not known in advance so I cannot use concrete C# model.

So I am using `Dictionary<string,object>` that represent a single object where `Key` will be the property name and `Value` will be the value of the property. Since client is posting collection i am using `List<Dictionary<string,object>>`

**ISSUE**

In controller's action method each dictionary has `Key` however corresponding value is NULL

**POSTMAN**

[image]

**Fiddler shows**

```
model%5B0%5D.FirstName=foo&model%5B0%5D.LastName=bar&model%5B1%5D.FirstName=james&model%5B1%5D.LastName=smith
```

Quick watch in model:

[image]

I tried using `JObject`, `ExpandoObject` as model with no luck

Comment: Why not just `POST` JSON instead? For example: `[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]`

Comment: i dont have control over client

Comment: Have you tried `model[0][0].Key = "FirstName"`, `model[0][0].Value = "Foo"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC Binding to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: That is how its being posted..check the Fiddler capture i posted

Comment: The point I'm making is that `FirstName` and `LastName` aren't valid properties on the `Dictionary` object. You need to assign the `Key` and `Value` properties. `FirstName` may simply be getting captured by the model binder which then possibly makes an assumption that `FirstName` should be the `Key` value. I'm working on a code sample at the moment to assist further.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the model type from `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` to `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` and it worked

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Update([FromForm]List<Dictionary<string, string>> model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```