# ASP.NET Core Binding to a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

In ASP.NET Core, can you bind dictionary values?

I saw in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary)  in a [more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683004/8684537) (not the one marked correct) it states:

> In ASP.NET MVC 4, the default model binder will bind dictionaries
> using the typical dictionary indexer syntax property[key].

Is this also true for ASP.NET Core MVC (and/or Razor Pages)?

Comment: Just a note: Binding to dictionaries works, if you have a `Dictionary<string, string>`. It will _not_ work (i.e. the value is always null) if you have a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's also true for ASP.NET Core MVC (and/or Razor Pages).

You can see the following is a simple demo in asp.net core.

Class:

```
 public class Command
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(Command command)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@model Command
<form asp-action="Test">
    <input type="text" name="Id" />
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Values[0].Key" value="Apple" />
    <input type="text" name="Values[0].Value" />
    //....
    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: will it allow you to reference it like this:
<input type="hidden" name="MyDictionary[MyKey]" value="MyValue" />

Comment: But isn't that just  binding the value to a specific "element" in the dictionary?

Comment: You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Rdp.gif).

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood your meaning before.

Comment: If you use `<input type="hidden" name="MyDictionary[MyKey]" value="MyValue" />`,it will bind to `{[Mykey,MyValue]}`

Comment: Just want to make sure I completely understand.  If this wasn't hidden and the user changed the value to "5" and submitted the page , would the Dictionary property  include a key value pair `Mykey: 5`  ?

Comment: Yes.It it will be.

Comment: You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeanj.gif)

Comment: Just a note: This works, if you have a `Dictionary<string, string>`. It will _not_ work (i.e. the value is always null) if you have a `Dictionary<string, object>`.